# Tomcat 8.5 ServletException JSP file not found (but it's 100% there)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat8, spring-webflow

I'm troubleshooting an issue in Tomcat 8.5.x that has me baffled.  **This issue affects only one deployment** (the DEV server);  the exact same sources & configs work perfectly everywhere else.

Here is an example stack trace (complete):

```
ERROR [uP-PortletExec-199-pr015-RENDER-[portlet-admin]] o.s.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet 2018-08-07 08:18:44,738 - Could not complete request
org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'listChannels' of flow 'portlet-manager'
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:573)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:227)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.portlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.startFlowRender(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:272)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.portlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handleRender(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:764)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:483)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:251)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.container.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:179)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.container.FilterChainImpl.processFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:95)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.container.FilterManagerImpl.processFilter(FilterManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:340)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.doGet(PortletServlet.java:261)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.invoke(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:233)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.render(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.dao.jpa.ThreadContextClassLoaderAspect.doThreadContextClassLoaderUpdate(ThreadContextClassLoaderAspect.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy356.render(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:157)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.PortletRendererImpl.doRender(PortletRendererImpl.java:456)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.PortletRendererImpl.doRenderMarkup(PortletRendererImpl.java:275)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletRenderExecutionWorker.callInternal(PortletRenderExecutionWorker.java:69)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletRenderExecutionWorker.callInternal(PortletRenderExecutionWorker.java:33)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletExecutionWorker$1.call(PortletExecutionWorker.java:185)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletExecutionWorker$ExecutionLifecycleCallable.call(PortletExecutionWorker.java:225)
    at org.apereo.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletExecutionCallable.call(PortletExecutionCallable.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: unnamed; URL [/WEB-INF/flows/portlet-mana
ger/listChannels.jsp]
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:208)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:293)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.doEnter(ViewState.java:185)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.portlet.PortletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;flows&#47;portlet-manager&#47;listChannels.jsp] not found
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.doDispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:222)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.portlet.PortletMvcView.doRender(PortletMvcView.java:67)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:204)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;flows&#47;portlet-manager&#47;listChannels.jsp] not found
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:408)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.renderView(ViewRendererServlet.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.processRequest(ViewRendererServlet.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.doGet(ViewRendererServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.doDispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:174)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Some additional points:

- That file -- `/WEB-INF/flows/portlet-manager/listChannels.jsp` -- is 100% there, exactly where it should be.
- This stack trace is only one example;  I'm getting similar errors for **every JSP file invoked within the same webapp**
- Other webapps are not affected;  their JSPs appear to be working

Has anyone ever seen anything like this issue?  Can anyone think of something else to check?

Comment: Do you really have `.jsp` files under `WEB-INF`?  That's a rather protected directory - you really don't want someone reading `WEB-INF/web.xml` for example.

Comment: We certainly do have `.jsp` files under `WEB-INF`.  Our JSPs are not available directly from a browser -- they are rendered by servlets using a `RequestDispatcher`.  I think the practice is pretty standard for Spring MVC.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this problem ? I have almost the same bug (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098531/servletexception-jsp-file-not-found-once-in-three-attempts-on-aws-bitnami-tomca?r=SearchResults) and I can’t find how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be file ownership issues. Try:

> find [tomcat_home] -! -user [expected_owner] -ls

That should show all the files that are not owned by [expected_owner].

If some files are found that do not belong to the user, try:

> sudo chown -R [expected_owner]:[expected_group] [tomcat_home]

Comment: To fix ownership under timcat:

Answer (score 1):

i think we should focus this message

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;flows&#47;portlet-manager&#47;listChannels.jsp] not found
```

why the file have this prefix `&#47;WEB-INF&#47;flows&#47;portlet-manager&#47;`

i guess this because you return is the empty string like this:

```
return ""
```